# positioned elements disappear under next positioned element in the flow in MSIE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

sometimes got into this problem but I have always avoided it using some alternative code.

Unfortunately, this time I need a hand.

in IE7 if two brother DIVS have "position:relative" absolute-positioned children of them disappear under the "next brother DIV"

http://jsfiddle.net/qN74X/

```
<div style="width:200px;position:relative;background:yellow;">XXX
    <div style="position:absolute;z-index:1;background:red;
                height:70px;top:0;left:50%;">ZZZ</div>
</div>

<div style="position:relative;width:200px;background:pink;">YYY</div>
```

how can I solve this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

When hovering over the element, set it's z-index as well (not just the tip). Here's the main change:

```
body > div{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
body > div:hover{
    z-index:5;
    border:0 none;
}
```

Basically, on the outer container (where the background was) was what needed to have it's z-index changed. I am also unsure of why I needed to put border:0 none but without it, it didn't work.

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/qN74X/3/

Comment: basically the concept is right, but the dom tree is more complicated than this, i have dozens of nested and adjacents divs that cause the problem... how i hate msie...